# I can't use the plugin module-formengine-etatcivil

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to use module-formengine-etatcivil in my project, but when I add the dependency of this plugin to the project I am getting build failure with the following trace:

```
Failed to execute goal on project portail: Could not resolve
 dependencies for  project fr.paris.lutece:portail:lutece-site:5.3.2:
 Failed to collect dependencies for
 fr.paris.lutece:portail:lutece-site:5.3.2: Could not resolve version
 conflict among [fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:3.1.7,
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:module-mylutece-cas:jar:1.1.8 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:[2.3.1-SNAPSHOT,5.0.0-SNAPSHOT),
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:plugin-html:jar:3.0.0 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:[2.3.0,5.0.0-SNAPSHOT),
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:plugin-teamnet:jar:1.2.0 ->
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:module-jpa-hibernate:jar:1.0.5 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:[2.4.0,4.0.0-SNAPSHOT),
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:plugin-teamnet:jar:1.2.0 ->
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:plugin-formengine:jar:2.3.0 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:[2.3.3,4.0.0-SNAPSHOT),
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:module-mylutece-teamnet:jar:1.2.0 ->
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:plugin-mylutece:jar:3.0.4 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:[3.1.6,4.0.0-SNAPSHOT),
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:library-teamnet:jar:1.2.0 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:3.1.7,
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:library-teamnetws:jar:1.2.0 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:3.1.7,
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:module-teamnet-creche:jar:1.2.0 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:3.1.7,
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:module-teamnet-creche:jar:1.2.0 ->
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:plugin-blobstore:jar:1.0.0 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:[3.0.0-SNAPSHOT,4.0.0-SNAPSHOT),
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:module-teamnet-prelevements:jar:1.2.0 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:3.1.7,
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:plugin-jcaptcha:jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:[2.4.0,5.0.0-SNAPSHOT),
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:plugin-contact:jar:3.0.1 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:[3.1.6,5.0.0-SNAPSHOT),
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:plugin-ganalytics:jar:0.0.5-SNAPSHOT ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:[2.2.4,5.0.0-SNAPSHOT),
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:module-formengine-etatcivil:jar:2.0.24-SNAPSHOT
 -> fr.paris.lutece.plugins:plugin-captcha:jar:1.0.1 -> fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:[4.1.0-SNAPSHOT,5.0.0-SNAPSHOT),
 fr.paris.lutece.plugins:library-lutece-unit-testing:jar:2.0.7 ->
 fr.paris.lutece:lutece-core:jar:RELEASE] -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency version problem with the dependency :
lutece-core-3.1.7 of your site and lutece-core:jar:[4.1.0-SNAPSHOT,5.0.0-SNAPSHOT) in the dependencies of plugin-captcha:jar:1.0.1.
Try the following things :
 - use an older version of plugin-captcha if it is compatible with lutece-core-3.1.7
 - exclude lutece-core dependency of plugin-captcha to force yours (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)
 - upgrade your version of lutece-core to a version in the range [4.1.0-SNAPSHOT,5.0.0-SNAPSHOT).